# How to upload Image from desktop in CKEditor in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I have tried lots of things but I could not find any solution for that, How can I upload an image from the desktop in CK Editor in Angular 6. How can I configure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write some code to insert images or links to images from your server path. 
Try that:

```
<ckbutton [name]="'imageExplorer'"
 [command]="'openImageExplorer'"
 (click)="openImageExplorer($event)"
 [icon]="'./images/Icon.png'"
 [label]="'Open image explorer'"
 [toolbar]="'insert,1'">
</ckbutton>
```

**Config File:**

```js
this.ckeConfig = {
            height: 400,
            language: "en",
            allowedContent: true,
            toolbar: [
                { name: "clipboard", items: ["Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "PasteText", "PasteFromWord", "-", "Undo", "Redo"] },
                { name: "links", items: ["Link", "Unlink", "Anchor"] },
                { name: "insert", items: ["Image", "Table", "HorizontalRule", "SpecialChar", "Iframe", "imageExplorer"] }
            ]
        };
```

In your dialog window insert the link:

```js
onAddImage() {
        try
        {
            let link = this.ckeditor.instance.document.createElement("img");
            link.setAttribute("alt", "Image");
            link.setAttribute("src", "./Images/test.png");

            this.ckeditor.instance.insertElement(link);
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            console.log((<Error>error).message);
        }

        this.showFiles = false;
    }
```

For [Documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_file_upload.html)

Hope it helps thanks.

Comment: Can you please create one demo on https://stackblitz.com with file name. Because I am not understanding how to implement. It will very helpful for me. Actually I am new in Angular